# why is this class method throwing an error: Attempt to call private method `create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting an error running the following method in an after_save callback

NoMethodError in ApprovalsController#update
Attempt to call private method `create'

```
 def create_next_approval
      self.recommendation.create :email => self.next_approver_email #if next_approver_email? && recently_approved?
 end
```

This method is giving me fits in general.  I am trying to create a new object after_save using an attribute: next_approver_email.

I also had to comment out the second part of the method because it was returning a no method error: next_approver_email?

I thought I could pass a ? to a method and it would check it?

Comment: Question marks are part of the method name, not an arbitrary symbol you can tack onto the end of an existing method; perhaps you want to check it for `blank?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model has been defined as `has_many :recommendations` then you have to use the plural form of the word eg:

```
self.recommendations.create :email => self.next_approver_email
```

As to checking the email - as the commenter mentioned, you can use empty?, or (better yet) present? eg:

```
self.recommendations.create :email => self.next_approver_email if next_approver_email.present? && recently_approved.present?
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, recommendation has_many Approvals in this case. So I am creating a new Approval relative to the Recommendation

Comment: also .present was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly, but here is a theory:

If you have a has_one relation for recommendation, you should be calling create_recommendation, not recommendation.create:

```
self.create_recommendation :email=>self.next_approver_email #if next_approver_email? && recently_approved?
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one